# $\cot^{-1}x = \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}$ Why are my methods of proving this true are wrong?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

$\cot^{-1}x = \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}$, $\forall$ $x\in R -$ {$0$}

Say I need to check if its true or not.

---

**METHOD 1**

Putting $\cot^{-1}x = \pi/2- \tan^{-1}x$

$$\Rightarrow \pi/2- \tan^{-1}x = \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}$$

$$\Rightarrow\pi/2 = \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}+ \tan^{-1}x$$

Using identity $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y= \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}$, we get

$$\Rightarrow\pi/2 = \tan^{-1}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}+x}{1-1}$$

$$\Rightarrow\pi/2 = \tan^{-1}\infty$$

So we can say that the statement is true.

---

**METHOD 2**

Let $\cot^{-1}x=\theta$, where $\theta$ is an angle of a triangle. So $\cot\theta =x$.

But $\cot \theta = \dfrac{1}{\tan \theta}$

So $\dfrac{1}{\tan \theta}=x$

$\Rightarrow \tan \theta = \dfrac{1}{x}$

$\Rightarrow \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x} = \theta $

$\Rightarrow \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x} = \cot^{-1}x$

So the statement is true.

---

But the true solution is in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520/proving-that-arctanx-arctan1-x-pm-pi-2-could-this-line-of-reasoning-p) through which we can clearly say that the above statement is false. I know I might have made every possible mistake in these two methods. I just want to know what are my mistakes and wrong assumptions.

Comment: Your first attempt is a proof in the wrong direction and it ends up with a nonsensical statement. So it cannot be correct.

Comment: @HansEngler that's what I am asking. Where did I go wrong? Which one was the wrong direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first method only shows that by starting with a false hypothesis you can reach a true conclusion.

Your second method stumbles at the step $\tan\theta={1\over x}\implies\theta=\tan^{-1}{1\over x}$.  There are *many* angles whose tangent is $1/x$; the inverse tangent function picks out a specific one, which may or may not be the angle you have in mind.

The easiest way to see that $\cot^{-1}x$ is not always equal to $\tan^{-1}(1/x)$ is to note that the inverse cotangent is always positive, while the inverse tangent function is negative for $x\lt0$.

Comment: Which one was the wrong hypothesis in the first method?

Comment: @manshu, it appears you began by assuming the conclusion when you went from $\pi/2-\tan^{-1}x=\cot^{-1}x$ to $\pi/2-\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}{1\over x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "$\cot^{-1}x = \tan^{-1}(1/x)$ for all real $x > 0$" is true, and careful inspection shows your second proof works in this case. To show "$\cot^{-1}x = \tan^{-1}(1/x)$ for all real $x \neq 0$" is false, it suffices to find *a single counterexample*. A simple choice is $x = -1$; tracing through each argument with that specific value will show where your reasoning goes astray.