# $\alpha $ is a root of equation $x^2 + 3x -\tan2 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha $ is a root of equation $x^2 + 3x -\tan2 = 0$ then $\cot^{-1} \alpha +\cot^{-1} \frac{1}{\alpha} -\frac{\pi}{2} $  cannot be equal to

1. $ \frac{\pi}{2}$
2. $ \frac{3\pi}{2}$
3. $ \frac{\pi}{1}$
4. $ 0$

For this I think I need to know the sign of $\alpha$ .
Just a hint is sufficient .

Comment: `cannot be equal to ` what?

Comment: @Bernard cannot be equal to... one of the 4 answers given below.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520/proving-that-arctanx-arctan1-x-pm-pi-2-could-this-line-of-reasoning-p

Comment: computing $\alpha$ and plugging this in the term below we get negativ results. Thus it cannot be answer 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Answer is 1,2,4

Comment: is $\cot^{-1}(x)$ equal to $arccot(x)$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only asked for a hint, here's a big one.

$\cot^{-1}\alpha + \cot^{-1}\frac1\alpha$ is actually a constant.  There are a few ways to prove this:

- Use the trig identity $\cot(x + y) = \frac{\cot x \cot y - 1}{\cot x + \cot y}$ with $x = \cot^{-1}\alpha$ and $y = \cot^{-1}\frac1\alpha$.
- Use the inverse trig identity $\cot^{-1}x + \cot^{-1}y = \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{xy - 1}{x + y}\right)$ with $x = \alpha$ and $y = 1/\alpha$.
- Use calculus to show that the derivative of $\cot x + \cot\frac1x$ is zero.

The third method won't tell you what the constant value is but I include the method for thoroughness.  I recommend using the second method.  The first method is more or less the same as the second method, just with extra steps.  Anyway, once you get the actual value of $\cot^{-1}\alpha + \cot^{-1}\frac1\alpha$, you'll immediately have the answer to your original question.

EDIT: Because of the rules of domains and ranges for inverse trig functions, the sign of $\alpha$ is important.  Both roots of $x^2 + 3x - \tan 2$ are negative.  Keep this in mind when evaluating $\cot^{-1}\alpha + \cot^{-1}\frac1\alpha$.

Comment: I think in this question just knowing the sign would be better .

Comment: @AakashKumar, I think you'll need to know more than just the sign.  But the sign is needed, updating my answer now...

Comment: @ritwiksinha Answer is 1,2.4

Comment: @ritwiksinha I added missing info to my answer.

Comment: @tilper Did you mean $ \alpha $ by constant value .

Comment: @AakashKumar I don't understand the question.  Did I mean $\alpha$ where?  $\alpha$ has one of two possible values.  The actual value of $\alpha$ doesn't matter.  All that matters is that $\alpha < 0$ (and we know this because both possible values of $\alpha$ are negative).  And $\cot^{-1}\alpha + \cot^{-1}\frac1\alpha$ is constant for $\alpha > 0$ and is a different constant for $\alpha < 0$ (as long as $\alpha$ and $1/\alpha$ are both in the domain of arccotangent).

Comment: @tilper the third method will tell you that the function is constant, so using $x=1$ say will give you the constant for $x>0$ and $x=-1$ will give you the constant for $x<0$.

Comment: @ZainPatel Indeed, thanks.  I didn't expand on that method because this question only has a trig tag.

Comment: @tilper I dont doubt you but i got I calculated it for $-1$ and i got $-\pi/2$.

Comment: @ritwiksinha, $\cot^{-1}(-1) = 3\pi/4$.  But note that there isn't really universal agreement for the range of arccotangent.  Some people take it to be $(0,\pi)$ and some people take it to be $[-\pi/2, 0) \cup (0, \pi/2]$.  Only OP will know for sure which range OP needs to use, but I suspect it's $(0,\pi)$ because the other range means all 4 answer choices would be selected.  And I guess that's technically a possibility but if I had to guess one way or the other, I wouldn't guess that all 4 are chosen.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

- $\dfrac\pi2<2<\pi$
- the sum of the roots is $-3$
- the product of the roots has sign opposite to $\tan 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ is a root of the equation then we have these two solutions
$$x=-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9+4 \tan (2)}\lor x=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9+4 \tan
   (2)}-\frac{3}{2}$$
is this right?
now we calculate $$\cot(\alpha)^{-1}+\cot(\frac{1}{\alpha})-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
is this right?
then we get $$-\frac{\pi }{2}+\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9+4 \tan
   (2)}}\right)-\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9+4 \tan
   (2)}\right)$$
or
$$-\frac{\pi }{2}-\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9+4 \tan
   (2)}\right)+\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9+4 \tan
   (2)}-\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$
is this right?
for both terms i got this value:
$$-3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620
   8998628034825342117068$$

Comment: Cotangent, not cosine.

Comment: and why the $-1$?

Comment: Dunno, wasn't me.