# Inverse functions of tan and proving results of it

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Let $x$ be a positive number and let $\Theta =\tan^{-1}x$
>
> Show that $\tan^{-1}\frac1x = \frac \pi2 - \Theta$ and hence show that $\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}\frac1x = \frac\pi2$ for $x > 0$
>
> Find $\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}\frac1x$ for $x<0$

(I know you have to use the fact that $\tan^{-1}x$ is odd)

I know this is significant somewhere.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Judging by your reputation, it seems you have been here for a while. Then why haven't you used proper formatting? This is really hard to read...

Comment: 4 days haha. I don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: Maybe [this helps](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: How do i write pi and inverse specifically

Comment: $\pi$ is written as `$\pi$` and $\tan^{-1}$ as `$\tan^{-1}$` etc. Take a look at the link. It's not that hard

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724348/what-is-arctanx-arctany   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is just one possible approach. Let $f : (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ be $f(x) = \arctan x + \arctan \frac 1 x$. Notice that

$$f'(x) = \frac 1 {1+x^2} + \frac 1 {1 + \frac 1 {x^2}} \left( - \frac 1 {x^2} \right) = \frac 1 {1+x^2} - \frac 1 {1+x^2} = 0 ,$$

which means that $f$ is constant. It remains to find out this constant value. In particular, it will be equal to $f(1)$ (chosen among others because it is easiest to evaluate). But

$$f(1) = \arctan 1 + \arctan \frac 1 1 = \arctan 1 + \arctan 1 = \frac \pi 4 + \frac \pi 4 = \frac \pi 2 ,$$

so $f(x) = f(1) = \frac \pi 2$.

Values other than $1$ that would have made evaluation easy would have been $\sqrt 3$ and $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$.

---

Alternatively, if you want to avoid derivatives, you could proceed using the trigonometric difference formula:

$$\qquad \tan(a-b) = \frac {\tan a - \tan b} {1 + \tan a \tan b}$$

which implies that

$$\tan \left(\frac \pi 2 - a \right) = \tan \left( \frac \pi 4 + \frac \pi 4 - a \right) = \frac {\tan \frac \pi 4 + \tan \left( \frac \pi 4 - a \right)} {1 - \tan \frac \pi 4 \cdot \tan \left( \frac \pi 4 - a \right)} = \frac {1 + \tan \left( \frac \pi 4 - a \right)} {1 - \tan \left( \frac \pi 4 - a \right)} = \\
\frac {1 + \frac {\tan \frac \pi 4 - \tan a} {1 + \tan \frac \pi 4 \cdot \tan a}} {1 - \frac {\tan \frac \pi 4 - \tan a} {1 + \tan \frac \pi 4 \cdot \tan a}} = \frac {1 + \frac {1 - \tan a} {1 + \tan a}} {1 - \frac {1 - \tan a} {1 + \tan a}} = \frac 2 {2 \tan a} = \frac 1 {\tan a} .$$

Rewriting your equality as $\arctan \frac 1 x = \frac \pi 2 - \arctan x$ and applying $\tan$ to both sides (because $\tan : (0, \frac \pi 2) \to (0, \infty)$ is bijective) you get

$$\frac 1 x = \tan \left( \arctan \frac 1 x \right) = \tan \left( \frac \pi 2 - \arctan x \right) = \frac 1 {\tan \arctan x} = \frac 1 x$$

which is a true equality, therefore the initial equality is also true.

---

To derive a similar formula for $x<0$ just remember that $\tan(-x) = -\tan x$ and use the identity that you already have.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with the observations i've made in my question?

Comment: @TripleA: Notice that my answer only *seems* more complicated than the others; in reality, what I do is that I also prove the identity $\tan (\frac \pi 2 - x) = \cot x$ that the others assume to be known.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x>0$, you have $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and $x=\tan\theta$.

Then
$$
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\cot\theta=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}=\frac{1}{x}
$$

You can conclude.

If $x<0$, then $\arctan x=-\arctan(-x)$. Set $y=-x$ and use the former identity.

Comment: What does arctan mean

Comment: @TripleA It's the same as your $\tan^{-1}$; sorry, but I find the notation $\tan^{-1}$ unclear and abusive.

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is correct. But there is a formal easy way. Let $x=\tan\theta$. If $x>0$ then we should consider $\theta>0$ and 
$$\cot\theta=\frac 1{\tan\theta}=\frac 1x$$
You may also know that $\cot\theta=\tan(\frac{\pi}2-\theta)$. Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac 1x&=\tan^{-1}\tan\theta+\tan^{-1}\cot\theta\\
&=\theta+\tan^{-1}\tan(\frac{\pi}2-\theta)\\&=\theta+\frac{\pi}2-\theta=\frac{\pi}2
\end{align}$$
You may also want to check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520). As a side-note, in your question you stated that
$$\tan(\frac{\pi}2-\theta)=\frac{1-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}$$
which is **wrong** and this equality holds for $\tan(\frac{\pi}4-\theta)$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out