# What is the value of $\arctan \left(\frac xy\right) +\arctan \left(\frac yx\right)?$

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I was playing about with some numbers when I came up with this fun question.

> What is the value of $\arctan \left(\frac xy\right) +\arctan \left(\frac yx\right)?$

Here is my method:
[image]
As is clearly evident from the triangle:
$a = \arctan \left(\frac yx\right)$ and
$b = \arctan \left(\frac xy\right)$
$\therefore \arctan \left(\frac xy\right) +\arctan \left(\frac yx\right) = a + b = 90^{\circ} = \frac {\pi}2 ^c$

Was my method right? Or can it be improved? I would appreciate any help in the comments or through answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assure you that both $x$ and $y$ are larger than $0$ else that triangle would have never appeared.

Comment: Ok then your answer is correct according to me! You wrote the expression, triangle was brought by you afterwards

Comment: @samjoe this is the first time I used $\arctan$ so I wanted to ask if it is identical to the $\tan^{-1}$ we all learnt before high school.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I am unsure what to do of that link. Could you help me out?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee was it to help me understand the difference between $\tan ^{-1}$ and $\arctan$? Or was my question a duplicate of it (doesn't seem so)?

Comment: it can also be -90 degrees

Comment: @Vasya it could be but I can restrict the range, right?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520/proving-that-arctanx-arctan1-x-pm-pi-2-could-this-line-of-reasoning-p

Comment: Because a triangle (generally) has angles $0<\theta<180$, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I could not find that question when I searched. Should I close this question?

Comment: Using \circ for degree symbol looks better in my opinion e.g compare $90^\circ$ and $90^0$

Comment: @kingW3 I personally did not know the exact symbol. The help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a correct method.

As an alternative note that for $x>0$

$$\arctan x + \arctan \frac1x = \frac{\pi}2$$

indeed if you set

$$y=\arctan \frac1x$$

then

$$\tan y=\frac1x$$

that is

$$x=\cot y=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)$$

therefore

$$\arctan x=\arctan\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-y=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan \frac1x$$

Comment: Should I close this question? As this is technically a duplicate as labbhattacharjee's link shows.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Probably some moderator will set it as a duplicate with a link at the previous.

Comment: Gimusi. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Using complex numbers:

Let $z = x + y \, i$ and $w = y + x \, i$. Then

$$
\arctan (\frac xy) +\arctan (\frac yx)
= \arg w + \arg z
= \arg wz
= \arg i (x^2 + y^2)
= \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: I intended to use $\frac {\pi}2$ but for a triangle isn't $90^0$ a more common convention?

Comment: Why $\arg w + \arg z = \arg wz$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\arctan\pars{x \over y}\ +\
\overbrace{\quad\qquad\arctan\pars{y \over x}\quad\qquad}
^{\ds{{\pi \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x \over y} - \arctan\pars{x \over y}}} & =
\bbx{{\pi \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x \over y}}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain what does $sgn$ mean?

Comment: I guess it means sign ...

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan $\mathrm{sgn}$ is the $\texttt{sign}$ function.
$\mathrm{sgn}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$.
$$
\mathrm{sgn}\left(x\right) \equiv
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
{\displaystyle -1} & \mbox{if} & {\displaystyle x} & {\displaystyle <} &
{\displaystyle 0}
\\
{\displaystyle 0} & \mbox{if} & {\displaystyle x} & {\displaystyle =} &
{\displaystyle 0}
\\
{\displaystyle 1} & \mbox{if} & {\displaystyle x} & {\displaystyle >} &
{\displaystyle 0}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: @FelixMarin thanks for explaining. I had _never_ seen this function before so my apologies.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Thanks. You're welcome. Also, it's related to the $\texttt{Heaviside Step Function}$ $\mathrm{H}$: $\mathrm{sgn}\left(x\right) = 2\,\mathrm{H}\left(x\right) - 1$ when $x \not= 0$..

Answer (score 1):

Funny I played with it too

$$E=\arctan \left(\frac xy\right) +\arctan \left(\frac yx\right)=x_1+x_2$$

$$ \tan(E)=\frac {\tan(x_1)+\tan(x_2)}{1-\tan(x_1)\tan(x_2)}$$

$$\tan(E)=\pm\infty$$

$$ \vdots $$

Comment: $E = \arctan \infty = $(b.a.a.) $\frac {\pi}2 $

Comment: yep @MohammadZuhairKhan +or - $\frac {\pi} 2$...I didnt understand why I got a zero at the denominator but it makes sense.

Comment: $\tan$ is periodic. I prefer $\pi \ge x \ge 0$ whenever possible.