# First Order Differential Equation $(2x/y-y/(x^2+y^2))dx+(x/(x^2+y^2)-x^2/y^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Where can I start to solve this differential equation:
$(2x/y-y/(x^2+y^2))dx+(x/(x^2+y^2)-x^2/y^2)dy=0$ .
[Differential Equation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcjI2.jpg) 
[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfHsE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$$ \dfrac {2xdx}y-\dfrac {x^2}{y^2}dy +{xdy-ydx\over x^2+y^2}=0$$
The DE becomes:
$$ \dfrac {2xdx}y-\dfrac {x^2}{y^2}dy +d \left(\arctan \left ( \dfrac y x \right) \right)=0$$

$$ \dfrac {dx^2}y+x^2d(\dfrac 1 y)+d \left(\arctan \left ( \dfrac y x \right) \right)=0$$
$$ d(\dfrac {x^2}y)+d \left(\arctan \left ( \dfrac y x \right) \right)=0$$
Integrate:
$$ \dfrac {x^2}y+ \arctan \left ( \dfrac y x \right) =C$$

Comment: Thank you but you have a mistake ı think.( xdy-ydx) is true one.

Comment: Sir, I ve found answer as: x^(2)/y+arctan(y/x)-arctan(x/y)=c

Comment: Could you look up my solution?

Comment: I have posted it as solution now I will post in question part too.

Comment: In which part I am wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yoiu're welcome @SemihAtaman

Comment: Sir my solution is true. Because we are treating y as a constant where we have dx and we are treating x as a constant where we have dy, because  of these we have c(x) and c(y) in my solution that they defines functions in x and in y. And also, I've watched a lot of videos about that topic. Here is one of them in the link below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnz5KcBMyo0&t=514s

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

By defining $u=\tan^{-1} {x\over y}$ and $w={x^2\over y}$ we obtain $$du={dx\over y(1+{x^2\over y^2})}-{dy\over x(1+{y^2\over x^2})}={ydx-xdy\over x^2+y^2}$$
$$
dw={2xdx\over y}-{x^2dy\over y^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Sir, which part is wrong? Is -arctan(x/y)=arctan(y/x) ?

@Aryadeva

[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUf03.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\dfrac {2x}y-\dfrac y{(x^2+y^2)}\right)dx+\left(\dfrac x{(x^2+y^2)}-\dfrac {x^2}{y^2}\right)dy=0$$
You can solve it with exactness. Since we have 
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
$$\partial_yM=\partial_xN$$
$$I=\int \dfrac {2x}y-\dfrac y{(x^2+y^2)}dx$$
$$I= \dfrac {x^2}y-\dfrac {dx/y}{((x/y)^2+1)}$$
$$I= \dfrac {x^2}y-\arctan (x/y)+C(y)$$
$$I= \dfrac {x^2}y+\arctan \left(\dfrac yx \right)+C_2(y)$$

On the other part we have:
$$I= \int \dfrac x{(x^2+y^2)}-\dfrac {x^2}{y^2}dy$$
$$I=\arctan \left(\dfrac yx \right)+\dfrac {x^2}{y}+C(x)$$
So we have :
$$C(x)=C_2(y) \implies C(x)=C$$
We can deduce the final answer as:
$$\boxed {\arctan \left(\dfrac yx \right)+\dfrac {x^2}{y}=C}$$

Comment: Thank you sir. I am so grateful. You gave a lot of effort for this question. Which property of arctan satisfies arctan(y/x)=-arctan(x/y)

Comment: You're welcome if that helps thats good. In fact you have $\arctan (y/x)+\arctan(x/y)=\frac {\pi}2$ @SemihAtaman Take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520/proving-that-arctanx-arctan1-x-pm-pi-2-could-this-line-of-reasoning-p/2147689