# How to prove the two answers to an integral are equivalent

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I'm trying to do the integral:
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}}dx$$
So I try two ways to do it, the first method I used is to multiply $e^x$ on both sides first.
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}}dx$$
$$=\int{\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}}dx$$
$$=\int{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}}\times\frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}}d\theta$$
$$=\theta+C$$
$$=\arcsin{(e^x)}+C$$
The second method is to do substitution directly.
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}}dx$$
$$=-\int{\frac{1}{u}\times\frac{u}{u^2+1}}du$$
$$=-\arctan{u}+C$$
$$=-\arctan{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}+C$$
$\text{After input them into desmos, I found out that the distances betweens the graphs is constant}\frac{\pi}{2}$
$\text{So I want to ask that, can you prove that,} $
$$\arcsin{(e^x)}-(-\arctan{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}})\text{ is a constant?}$$

Comment: Hint: set $e^x= \sin \theta$

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but I still want to point out that, assuming your calculations are correct, you just proved that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that
$$\sin^{-1}e^x = \tan^{-1} \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}
= \frac{\pi}2- \tan^{-1} {\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}
$$

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer, as it shows how the substitution $e^x=\sin\theta$ isn't necessary when proving the results equal. My answer just builds off of yours to show from there that the two result are equal.

Comment: Maybe just mention that we're using these two results: ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions)) $\sin^{-1} x = \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$; and ([2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520)) $\tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x} = \frac \pi 2$ (for $x>0$)

Answer (score 18):

You can compute the derivatives:

$$\arcsin'y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} ,$$
$$\arctan'y = \frac{1}{1+y^2} .$$
This shows that the derivative of $\arcsin{(e^x)}-(-\arctan{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}})$ is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}e^x +  \frac{1}{1+e^{-2x} -1}\frac 1 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}(-2e^{-2x}) = \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}} \\=  \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}} - \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1 -e^{2x}}} = 0 .$$
Hence  $\arcsin{(e^x)}-(-\arctan{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}})= C$.

With $x = 0$ we get
$$C  = \arcsin 1 + \arctan 0 = \frac{\pi}{2} + 0 = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: I like this answer a lot. “How do I show this function is constant?” “Take its derivative and see if it is zero.”

Comment: Why bother computing the derivatives? By the integration proof in the OP, you can just state that both functions have the same derivative. I don't think this answer adds anything. (sorry, I don't mean to be mean!)

Comment: @preferred_anon I disagree, the answer does add something, namely a general method that works in various scenarios, not only the specific scenario in the OP.

Comment: @preferred_anon The question was "So I want to ask that, can you prove that
$\arcsin{(e^x)}-(-\arctan{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}})$  is a constant?" You are right that this is implicit in the OP's  computations,  but I think he wanted to get an alternative confirmation.

Comment: @KritikerderElche I agree with you - my claim is that this isn't really an alternative confirmation. OP proves that $F' = G'$ by computing the indefinite integral in two different ways. When I read this answer and look for an "a-ha" moment, I see two things cancel out, and say: Oh, of course, that's what I just integrated. Why do the algebra?

Answer (score 2):

**You have already proved it, by doing those integrals!**  If you compute the same indefinite integral in multiple ways, then (provided your computations were correct) whatever answers you get *must* be equal up to a constant.

But in case you’re not quite confident of your original calculations, **you can check them by differentiating the solutions and checking they give the same answer**, which should be the body of your original integral.  That is, if you can show $f'(x) = g'(x)$, that means $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)-g(x)) = 0$, so the difference $f(x)-g(x)$ is constant.  [Paul Frost’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4884977/2439) goes through the details of this for your functions.

(Here I’m assuming that the solutions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ are defined on a connected domain.  If there are holes in their domain, typically coming from singularities in the integrand, like e.g. $\int \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$, then the different between the solutions is only *locally constant* — the solutions must still agree up to some constant within each connected component of their domain, but the constant can be different on different components.)

Answer (score 1):

From @Quanto's answer, we know that$$\arcsin(e^x)=\pi/2-\arctan\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}$$Now, our expression becomes$$\pi/2\require{cancel}-\arctan\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}-(-\arctan\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1})\\=\pi/2\cancel{-\arctan\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}\cancel{+\arctan\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}\\=\pi/2$$So the two results differ by just $\pi/2$, just like what you observed.